# How can I call javascript function in Model or Controller in Cakephp?

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I have to call a javascript function from my Model or Controller. I can call it from the view file but how can I call a JS function directly from Model.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you should only be calling client side code from the view. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a notification model. From afterSave function, I want to call a JS push Notification function.

Comment: The solution is to call a controller function and write the js code in view file. But is there any way to directly call it from Model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server side language. This means the PHP file will get processed on the HTTP server and then deliver the generated HTML page to the client.

Javascript (JS) is interpreted on the the client (browser) and interfaces with the HTML and other remote resources.

Due to this model, PHP and JS know nothing about each other. So to call JS directly from the PHP file is not possible.

If you are looking to make a client browser call a JS function and the PHP script defines the values for the JS function you can use echo() and some string concatenation

```
//this is an example and will not run.    
echo "<script>myJsFunction('" . $arg1 . "','" . $arg2 . "')</script>";
```

This will embed the JS function call in the HTML page returned to the client. Once the client renders the HTML page it will execute the function call as it comes across it.

If you could give an example of what you trying to do I might be able to give you a more accurate answer.

For a deeper explanation of the client server architecture and where things get executed have a look at [Web Browser Client Server Architecture](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/basics/client_server_architecture.php3)

Answer (score 1):

No, try understanding the MVC pattern, the idea is that the model is **not** aware of the view and doesn't have to be. Also you can't call JS with php, which is a server side language and doesn't know anything about the client side scripts.

What you want is to implement long polling. I recommend you to learn and read about the basic technologies involved before trying to implement something.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Comment: I am sending notifications across models and controllers. Each notification has an entry in Database. Now, in Notification Model, I have written an afterSave method. On the other hand, I have written function in JS to send real time notifications.  
Now, i want that after saving a notification in DB, call the JS function to send the notification to FireBase Server. I can do this in view also, but, in that case i will have to check every activity and add my code multiple times. That's why I want to use it after Save.

Comment: I know MVC and Push Technology. I can do it in View File also, but the question is how can I call JS function from Model or Controller. Basically, the function should be triggered in afterSave function so that I do not miss any notification.

Comment: I can assure you that you *don't* understand it based on your last comment.

Comment: @RomishaAggarwal Firebase has a [**REST API**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/quickstart.html), that is what you use to [**push data**](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-post) from a server side application.